# Change an API Route Name in Swagger

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, swagger-ui

does anybody have an idea on how to change the name of a API call on swagger for exact it shows as **'/api/Users'** but I want it to show as **'GetUsersByID'**  if you see in the picture below its just got the route. I've tired using `[HttpGET("{id}", Name = "GetUsersByID")]` but swagger seems to ignore this.
[Screenshot Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkke1.png)

I am using .Net Core 3.1 and the latest swashbuckle nuget. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: do you want to only change the name in swagger or you actually want to change the endpoint?

Comment: @nalnpir I guess to change the endpoint would you put the changes in the app.UseEndpoints in the configure function ?, but for this I just wanted the swagger name to change.

Comment: Not really, my point is do you want people accessing from api/Users or api/GetUsersByID . My question is, because swagger is showing the path where you can actually hit the GET api call. Its weird that you actually want to rename that

Comment: Oh sorry yes I want to be able to do it by using api/getusersbyid

Comment: I think I understood it wrong to be fair @nalnpir I want the endpoint to be GetUserByID so I can do calls like ‘myapitest.com/GetUsersByID?Id=1&format=json’

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about the format, as far as I'm reading is automatically, and comes with the framework, but it works upon the header you send, by default is json, if you specify xml it will be xml

But what you want to achieve is pretty easy, change your tags of the method it should look something like this

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("GetUsersByID")]
public async Task<IActionResult> YourMethod(int id)
{
    //code of your method
}
```